# Как исправить запрос к mysql

Tags: php, mysql

В базу нужно отправить значение $exp_cig5 именно к уникальному $id
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO id='$id' (experience) VALUES('$exp_cig5')");
Но он не работает, подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если у вас в БД уже есть запись с таким id
то возможно вам нужна такая инструкция:

---

UPDATE <ВашаТаблица> SET <ВашеПоле> = <ВашеЗначение>
WHERE id = <ЗначениеВашегоУникальногоId>

Comment: Спасибо, работает